# Awk to multiply all numbers in a text file by a constant subject to another constraint

Tags: awk

I have files with contents like the following:

```
0.23423
0.10093
0.44231
0.45630
0.89999
```

I want to increase every number by a given percentage, say, 20%.  So, I want to know how to multiply each value by 1.2.

The "constraint" I need to impose is that the products be less than or equal to 1, because these values are probabilities.

So, in pseudocode, I need to replace each number `X` in a given text file by `max(1.0,X*1.2)`.

How can this be acheived in Awk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one-liner:

```
awk '{p=1.2*$0;$0=p>1?1:p}7' file
```

test with your example:

```
kent$  cat f
0.23423
0.10093
0.44231
0.45630
0.89999

kent$  awk '{p=1.2*$0;$0=p>1?1:p}7' f
0.281076
0.121116
0.530772
0.54756
1
```

if you want to keep the precision of the floats, you could use `printf`:

```
awk '{p=1.2*$0;$0=p>1?1:p;printf "%.5f\n",$0}' file
```

with same input, it gives:

```
kent$  awk '{p=1.2*$0;$0=p>1?1:p;printf "%.5f\n",$0}' f
0.28108
0.12112
0.53077
0.54756
1.00000
```

Comment: What do you mean by keep the precision of the floats?  Do you mean, prevent the introduction of additional insignificant digits, and prevent the trailing zeros from being removed?

Comment: @synaptik yes, to keep the number format as same as the input, in case this was needed.

Comment: whats the '7' for at the end of the one-liner  awk '{p=1.2*$0;$0=p>1?1:p}7'?

Comment: @FrodeAkselsen it does default action: `print`

Answer (score 3):

Using the C-like *ternary operator* in a one-liner :

```
awk '{res = $1 * 1.2; print (res > 1) ? 1 : res}' file
0.281076
0.121116
0.530772
0.54756
1
```