# How to multiply all integers in a text file on windows 7 given another constraint?

Tags: windows, algorithm, math, specifications

I have a text file organized like this:

beep(E1, 128);

beep(D2, 137);

beep(F0, 36);

beep(E2, 36);

beep(E2, 41);

. . .

and I need to multiply the *second* integer in each line by a given constant, with the first integer being unchanged and the output being an integer (could be next up, next down or nearest from multiplied answer; it doesn't matter much). There won't be a time when the first integer goes above 10 or the second one goes below 10, if that helps. Here's an example output given a multiplier of .5:

beep(E1, 64);

beep(D2, 69);

beep(F0, 18);

beep(E2, 18);

beep(E2, 21);

. . .

I realize this is similar to this question: [Awk to multiply all numbers in a text file by a constant subject to another constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431123/awk-to-multiply-all-numbers-in-a-text-file-by-a-constant-subject-to-another-cons), but I didn't feel the answers there suited my needs. Any and all help towards a solution is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please come back with a programming related question... not the requirements of a program we should build for you

Comment: Would anybody mind telling me why I'm getting down-voted for his when the question I linked to didn't? I assumed this was an acceptable question given the fact that it's so similar to that one. Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431123/awk-to-multiply-all-numbers-in-a-text-file-by-a-constant-subject-to-another-cons

Comment: That question you're referring to gives a specific programming language. Windows 7 is not a programming language. In order to increase your chances of getting an answer, you should edit your question to specify what language you are trying to write this in (and add the appropriate tags). Showing what you tried so far and what problems your running into would be an even better way to get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your question and following your link I decided to learn awk. I believe this will solve your problem. 'p' is used as your constant.

Linux:

```
awk '{if(length($0)>0){p=0.5;print $1,int(substr($2,0,length($2)-1)*p)");"}}' filename
```

Windows:

```
awk "{if(length($0)>0){p=0.5;print $1,int(substr($2,0,length($2)-1)*p)\");\"}}" filename
```

Both versions have been tested.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is the kind of thing I would pay money for (specific and small coding requests).